# Pass Parameters to Rails Unit Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, nunit

I was wondering if there is a way to pass arguments to individual tests in rails similar, or similar in idea, to NUnit's [TestCase Attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.2).  Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you do parameterized tests in Ruby (and Python) is to dynamically create the test methods:

```
[[12, 3, 4], [12, 2, 6], [12, 4, 3]].each do |n, d, q|
  test "#{q} is the quotient of #{n} and #{d}" do
    assert_equal q, n/d
  end
end
```

Make certain that the test names include the data.

Comment: Won't n, d, and q be arrays variables and not numbers?

Comment: Each element of the main array is an array of 3 items.  when you split the arguments into |n, d, q| they are assigned to each element of that 3 item array. Thus the first round they will be n = 12, d = 3, q = 4, and the second time they will be n = 12, d = 2, q = 6, etc.

Comment: Note that this pattern may create issues for the general case, as I explained in [this blog post](http://blog.nikhaldimann.com/2013/01/23/robust-parametrized-unit-tests-in-ruby/). You can use the [param_test gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/param_test) to simplify this a bit.